# What is the result for stored procedure with in ,out parameters and IS keyword parameters before procedure body

Tags: oracle, mybatis

Procedure with in , out parameters and having IS keyword with parameters list before BEGIN. In this case which result we will get after executing procedure.

```
PROCEDURE sample_proc (id in VARCHAR2, name in VARCHAR2, Course out varchar2)
IS error EXCEPTION, error_code VARCHAR2(100), courseID NUMBER, price NUMBER
BEGIN
 select * from student where ID =id and name=name;
END executePROC;
```

Which fields we will get as result after executing via mybatis.

The stored procedure having parameters with data type before BEGIN keyword.  In this case the parameters after IS and Before BEGIN keyword how it will work.  Please explain

Answer (score 3):

> Which fields we will get as result after executing via mybatis.

None, the code has syntax errors and will not compile in Oracle.

You have:

- A statement starting with `PROCEDURE` and not `CREATE PROCEDURE` (assuming that it is not part of a package as you do not include a preceding `CREATE PACKAGE` statement).
- `,` following the variable declarations and not `;`
- A `SELECT` statement in the PL/SQL scope that does not have an `INTO` clause.
- `WHERE id = id AND name=name` is (almost) the same as doing `WHERE 1=1 AND 1=1` as the `id` and `name` values on both sides of the equality comparison will be from the local scope of the SQL statement and will not reference the procedure's arguments.
- Variables that you are not using.
- The procedure's identifier does not match the identifier after the final `END` statement.

To fix it you want something like:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE sample_proc (
  i_id     in  STUDENT.ID%TYPE,
  i_name   in  STUDENT.NAME%TYPE,
  o_Course out STUDENT.COURSEID%TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN
 SELECT courseid
 INTO   o_course
 FROM   student
 WHERE  id   = i_id
 AND    name = i_name;
END sample_proc;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=75b8bc21522f043f0fa160a7928155e1)*

Comment: Data base team already created and provided that stored procedure. Sample I have give. The stored procedure having parameters with data type before BEGIN keyword.  In this case the parameters after IS and Before BEGIN keyword how it will work.  Please explain

Comment: @user3898783 You tagged the question as Oracle. Your code does not compile in an Oracle database. Check the linked db<>fiddle for the errors and the debugging steps to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

> IS keyword with parameters list before BEGIN.

They are not parameters, they are local variables.

As MTO has explained, the example you gave is not valid for a number of reasons.

But for the sake of argument, if you did actually have something like:

```
... PROCEDURE sample_proc (...)
IS
  error EXCEPTION;
  error_code VARCHAR2(100);
  courseID NUMBER;
  price NUMBER;
BEGIN
...
```

then the bit between `IS` and `BEGIN` is the optional declaration part, [as described in the documention](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-subprograms.html#GUID-855AA11F-32CB-4CAD-9255-BE92A6821487):

> **Declarative part (optional)**
>
> This part declares and defines local types, cursors, constants, variables, exceptions, and nested subprograms. These items cease to exist when the subprogram completes execution.
>
> This part can also specify pragmas.
>
> Note: The declarative part of a subprogram does not begin with the keyword `DECLARE`, as the declarative part of an anonymous block does.

The bit that is particularly relevant to your question (as I understand it anyway) is "*These items cease to exist when the subprogram completes execution.*" They are *local* variables for use within the procedure, and not visible to or accessible by whatever calls the procedure.

The only data made visible to the caller is whatever it put into the `OUT` parameters.

Comment: From Oracle 12c it is not only with `out` parameter, but with`dbms_sql.return_result` in the body

Comment: Thank you @Alex Poole for the explanation.  The procedure caller will get results error,error_code, course_id, price along with out parameters as results right along after execution